# Autodesk Model Derivative API - Can't translate my revit file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm doing this tutorial from [here](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prepare-file-for-viewer/):

[image: Tutorial]

I have a sample revit file from revit itself, I saved it as: **test1.rvt**

- I get my access token [it works]
- I create my bucket [it works]
- I check if my bucket exists [it works]
- I upload test1.rvt [it works]
- I translate the file with the urn, encoded in 64bit [result: success]
- **I verify the translation [it fails]**

I don't understand my problem here. The eror says:

> The file is not a Revit file or is not a supported version

But I have tried with the revit file from the homePage (revit 2017 and 2018) so what can be my problem here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: It is about the API from Autodesk. So yes it is a programming question.
Maybe I'm doing something false in my request to the API.

Comment: It seems pretty good about the process, the only suspicious I can see is that I usually do not specify the Content-Length while uploading the file. Can you send your file to me at zhong.wu@autodesk.com, and I can verify it at my hand.

Comment: Thanks, I have send you the file.

Comment: Simply use our online viewer to test if the problem comes from your code or the file itself: https://a360.autodesk.com/viewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just verified your revit file, it's working good with the translation service, here is my body of translation job API:

```
{
  "input" : {
    "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0c*******m9uc29mdHdhcmV3b3Jrc2hvcDIvdGVzdHJ2dC5ydnQ"

  },
  "output" : {
    "force": "true",
    "destination": {
      "region": "us"
    },
    "formats": [
      {
        "type": "svf",
        "views": ["2d", "3d"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that!